# Jquery Select a Div and trigger another div that is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, optimization

I'm trying to make an infobox that pops out when the mouse is over a related image.
But only succeeded to pop it out and make it flash because when it pops out u literally leave the image...

I've already tried to only show it when the mouse is over the image, by using .mouseenter and FadeIn instead of fadeToggle, but there is a bug that makes it pops out every second hover on the image.

My code (contain NodeJS - EJS extention):

**HTML:**

```
 <section class="campview">
        <h1>Most Popular Campgrounds</h1>
          <hr>
           <div class="container-fluid">
               <div class="row">
                  <%  for(var i=0 ; i<4 ; i++){ %>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                        <img src="<%=campgrounds[i].image%>" class="image-responsive img-rounded animated fadeIn">
                           <div class="infopop">
                               <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                     <h3><%=campgrounds[i].name%> </h3>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                             <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7">
                                       <p class="vert-center"><%= campgrounds[i].description.slice(0,100)+"..." %></p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5">
                                     <a href="/campgrounds/<%=campgrounds[i]._id%>" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                   </div>
                 <% }; %>

                </div>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                     <a class="pull-right" href="/campgrounds">View all campgrounds</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
   </section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.infopop{
    display: none;
   z-index: 1;
   position: absolute;
   top: 57%;
   width: 92.8%;
   height: 40%;
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(50,50,50,0)),
        to(rgba(50,50,50,0.8)), color-stop(.3,#000)
     );
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".campview img").hover(function(event){
              $(this).next().fadeToggle("fast");
     });
});
```

Hope you would understand me (:
Thanks!

Comment: the hover event trigger all the time that you are on the element. so you either should check it that already faded or not, or you can do that by css rule :hover

Comment: I have used :hover, but don't want to work hard on the fade animation, this is why I picked Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a class to check if your next item is opened and then assign an "mouseleave" event so you won't depend anymore of `$(".campview img")` while the image is opened.

I have attached a working snippet. I wrapped your `img` and `.infopop` into their own wrapper `.camp-block`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
   $(".camp-block img").on("mouseenter", function(event) {
 
     event.stopImmediatePropagation();

     var $myNext = $(this).next();
     if (!$myNext.hasClass("isOpened")) {
       $myNext.addClass("isOpened");

        $myNext.bind("mouseleave", function(ev) {

         $(this).removeClass("isOpened").unbind("mouseleave")

       }); 
     }
   });
 })
```

```css
.camp-block {
  width: 94%;
  margin: 0 3%;
  position: relative;
}

.camp-block img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.camp-block .infopop {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50%;
}
.camp-block .infopop.isOpened{
  z-index: 3;
}
.camp-block .infopop.isOpened .bottom-block{
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.camp-block .infopop .bottom-block {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(50, 50, 50, 0)), to(rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8)), color-stop(.3, #000));
}


}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section class="campview">
  <h1>Most Popular Campgrounds</h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="camp-block">
          <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg" class="image-responsive img-rounded animated fadeIn">
          <div class="infopop">
            <div class="bottom-block">
              <h5>custom headline 1</h5>
              <p>
                some text
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="camp-block">
          <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg" class="image-responsive img-rounded animated fadeIn">
          <div class="infopop">
            <div class="bottom-block">
              <h5>custom headline 2</h5>
              <p>
                some text
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="camp-block">
          <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg" class="image-responsive img-rounded animated fadeIn">
          <div class="infopop">
            <div class="bottom-block">
              <h5>custom headline 3</h5>
              <p>
                some text
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="camp-block">
          <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg" class="image-responsive img-rounded animated fadeIn">
          <div class="infopop">
            <div class="bottom-block">
              <h5>custom headline 4</h5>
              <p>
                some text
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <a class="pull-right" href="/campgrounds">View all campgrounds</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Update with explanation**

So i wrapped `img` and `.infopop` into `.camp-block` so you can keep the spaces between your block provided by bootstrap's classes `.col-sm-*` that adds padding.

Then i added `position:relative` to `.camp-block` so i can `position:absolute` the `img` tag.

**Ordering Elements**

When you first enter the site the elements must have a default position.
Your `img` must be on top (`z-index:2`) over .infopop(`z-index:1`) so jQuery can trigger the `mouseenter` event.

Keep in mind that `.infopop` has `padding-top:50%` to push `.bottom-block` further from the top, and that `.infopop` without the class `.isOpened` will ensure that `.bottom-block` has an `opacity` of 0.

**Triggering JQuery**

When you hover over the image, jquery will trigger and add a class `.isOpened` to `.infopop` , `.isOpened` will change `.infopop` css `z-index` to 3 so now `.infopop` is over the `img` and will change `.bottom-block` `opacity` to 1. JQuery will also bind a `mouseleave` event on `.infopop`, but when `.infopop` will show, your cursor is already over it so the only event that could trigger next is a `mouseleave` event that is designed to remove `.isOpened` class and change things back to normal.

Comment: It Works! but there is a little bug that u may fix: when mouseover ".campview img" it pops out, then mouseover ".infopop", and then when I to it again, without mouseleave ".campview img", it pops out and pops in one time again. and it I go right before it to another ".campview. img" it doesn't disappear. attach link to explain better: https://ex01-yahavf6.c9users.io/ . thank you!

Comment: I have updated the code to search for opened boxes `$(".isOpened)` and close them before showing the new one you're hovering over.

Comment: WOW! work just perfect! Many thanks, my friend! hope you can explain your thinking flow. so i"ll learn the new methods you have used.

Comment: @Cod3N0de i have updated my answer with an explanation. I hope it makes things more clear for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead of the above:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".campview img").hover(function(){
                  $(this).siblings('.infopop').css('display', 'block');
         }, function() {
                  $(this).siblings('.infopop').css('display', 'none');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Nope, It doesn't work.
only flash 100 times faster. and no fadeToggle. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
.fade {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   }

   .fade:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
      }
```

Comment: possible, but i need to add it any element inside the hidden div, so it kinda a lot of work (:

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who will need this in the future, I'm sharing my solution.
that I think it is the simplest that can be achieved.
I'v just select that the ".col" that contains the img, will be the only elemnt that will fadeOut the ".infopop".

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".infopop").hide();
  $(".campview img").mouseenter(function(event){
  $(this).next().fadeIn();
  });
  $(".campview div.col-xs-12.col-sm-3").mouseleave(function(event){
    $(".infopop").fadeOut();
  });

});
```